# MongoServerError: not authorized on app to execute command on docker container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker to connect node and mongo and I am trying to insert data in a database. All the containers are up and running. And it is running perfectly on my local machine but in the server I get the following error.

```
 MongoServerError: not authorized on app to execute command { insert: "users", documents: [ { username: "riwaj", password: "$2a$12$C3hpChig42coIoMEbtegsepw7tJeflHqpW7x.0/jPseX6G5KUXWO.", _id: ObjectId('63d41dc11d038db2b950a744'), __v: 0 } ], ordered: true, lsid:....
```

This clearly states that the user `riwaj` is not allowed to perform insert operation on the database. However, I have defined the necessary attributes required for mongo container as mentioned in the documentation in my docker-compose file which are:

- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=riwaj
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=dummypasswordxx

The users are created as per the credentials but I checked it by going into the interactive shell of the container and executing the following command

`mongosh -u riwaj -password`

However even here if I try to insert data into a database using the mongo insert() function I get a similar error related to authorization.

For more reference here is my docker-compose files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

  node-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo

#adding mango container
  mongo: #service name for mongo
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=riwaj
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db #Named volume for data persistance
#adding redis container
  redis:
    image: redis
    

volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginx:
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  node-app:
    build: 
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: production
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
      - MONGO_USER=${MONGO_USER}
      - MONGO_PASSWORD=${MONGO_PASSWORD}
      - SESSION_SECRET=${SESSION_SECRET}
    command: node index.js
  mongo:
    environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
        - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE= app
```

It is clear the issue is with authorization but shouldn't the root user have all the authorization to do all read-write operations? Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/Riwajchalise/node-docker where the project is pushed the endpoint for the signup api is mentioned in the `Readme file`

Would be really helpful if you can contribute in any way